# Atmosphere Pubsub example error on weblogic 12c

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, atmosphere

The pubsub example of atmosphere is deployed to weblogic 12c.

with the below small change i deployed the app

```
        var request = {

            url :document.location.toString()+'ws/pubsub/' + getElementByIdValue('topic'),
```

Gives the following error...

**On server side**
 *org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol BEA-000000 Status code higher or equal than 400 Status 405 Message Method Not Allowed*

**In script console(chrome)**

***Network**

ERROR: 405:Method Not Allowed
ERROR: 405:Method Not Allowed
message=testing pubsub sent trying to use websocket*

**console**
GET =1396276957934">http://localhost:7001/atmosphere/ws/pubsub/Test?X-Atmosphere-Transport=close&X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=&=1396276957934 400 (Bad Request) atmosphere.js:1816
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:7001/atmosphere/ws/pubsub/Test?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.1.4-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=0&X-atmo-protocol=true' failed: Received a broken close frame containing a reserved status code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

```
document.location.toString()
```

needs to be modified to

```
document.location.origin+'/atmosphere/ws/pubsub/'
```

to skip the name of the html file(if not index.html) .

The atmosphere handler will take care of the operation and connects to websockets as intended.

The long polling needs to be addressed as a seperate url , as the weblogic-12c adds /ws/ to context path  automatically, when it detects websocket stuff

refer to 
[complete solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328544/getting-error-on-pubsub-example-using-atmosphere-jersey/22766252#22766252)